# Passing web request context transparently to a celery task

Tags: python, flask, celery

I've a multi-tenant setup where I'd like to pass certain customer specific information, specifically *request.host* to the celery task, where ideally it should be available in a global variable. Is there a way to set this up, in a manner transparent to the application?

the task would be called the same way:

```
my_background_func.delay(foo, bar)
```

the task is defined the same way, except that it has access to a global variable called 'request' having an attribute 'host':

```
@celery_app.task
def my_background_func(foo, bar):
    print "running the task for host:" + request.host
```

Answer (score 0):

here's how I solved it ...

```
class MyTask(Task):
    abstract = True
    def delay(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.apply_async(args, kwargs, headers={'host': request.host})
```

on the client:

```
 @celery_app.task(base=MyTask, bind=True)
 def hellohost(task):
     return "hello " +  task.request.headers['host']
```

it works, but strangely hellohost.delay().get() hangs on the client